# How can express and jade does not compress html?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I using express and jade, but when I debug I doesn't want jade compress my html, are there any way to pass an option jade globally and make it does not compress html.

Comment: do you mean that you want the jade template to show when you view the source of the page?

Comment: He means he wants to turn off compression during compilation for the jade middleware.  I believe.  At least that's what I want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the time since this answer was written an option has been added to control this behaviour.

```
app.locals.pretty = true;
```

<strike>At the moment, no. This feature has been discussed here:</strike>

https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/pull/205

The html doesn't actually get compressed or minified by default, though. It's just not formatted nicely. The simplest way I've found to make it human-readable is to use Chrome's dev tools, which give you a nice foldable representation of the source.

Comment: I asked TJ. use `app.set('view options', {pretty: true});`

Comment: @guilin桂林 This should not be the accepted answer.  The answer with the most upvotes is the correct one

Comment: Thanks, @light24bulbs. The answer was wrong. I've updated it to be more correct.

Answer (score 28):

If you use Express 3.x, you can control compression via app.locals.pretty. I usually enable it while development:

```
app.configure('development', function () {
    app.locals.pretty = true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jade Comments to annotate your code for viewing in the browser.

```
//h1
h1 Some Title
//p
p some content
```

will output

```
<!--h1-->
<h1>Some Title</h1>
<!--p-->
<p>some content</p>
```

The template is already compiled once it leaves the server, so if you wanted to view the template in the browser you would have to write a plugin that de-compiles html to jade and than display the decompiled version.

Comment: Shouldn't those HTML comments be <!-- --> ?

Comment: @Zikes afaik, jade outputs HTML comments for // and completely ignores /// comments.

Answer (score 1):

Huh, new to nodejs so maybe missing something here; but in **app.js** adding `app.set('view options', {pretty: true});` was ineffectual (using *express 3.0.3*).

..doesn't appear to be supported? did find a workaround, e.g. on a per route basis:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', {
    [... other stuff ...]
    pretty: true
  });
};
```

Comment: If you look at Andy's answer, it's pretty much the same. (`res.render('index', { /* view.locals */ })`).  If you set it on the app.locals, it extends to all your `res.render()` calls.  [Some documentation on how app/view locals work.](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.locals)

Answer (score 0):

For whom using pug-cli, you need to add `--pretty` in cmd(terminal). Like the following,

```
pug --pretty -w -o dist/html/ assets/pug/index.pug
```